# Add Developer Link on Homepage Only

Tags: links, homepage, footer

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?> | Developed by: <a href="https://mohsinalam.com" target="_blank">Mohsin Alam</a><?php } ?>


<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> | Developed by: <a href="https://mohsinalam.com" target="_blank">Mohsin Alam</a><?php } ?>
```

I tried each code to put my link as developer credit on a homepage only, but it didn't work. The developer credit link inset on every page! Is my code correct or need any correction? How can I execute the developer link on the homepage only? Thanks

Note: I am using Astra themes. The code I put in Customizer > Footer > Footer Bar.

Comment: Please note that third party themes, such as Astra, are considered off-topic here. Should you have any questions regarding the setup, usage or customization of such themes please contact the theme author to recieve appropriate support.

Comment: I want to know if this code is correct or not. Thanks